# Openshift git push fails without or with jenkins

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, jenkins, openshift

I:
-do some random changes
-git add them, commit and push

Then, the push goes somewhere like this

```
Counting objects: 13, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (8/8), done.
Writing objects: 100% (8/8), 825 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 8 (delta 6), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: : command not found
remote: An error occurred executing 'gear prereceive' (exit code: 127)
remote: Error message: CLIENT_ERROR: Failed to execute: 'control stop' for /var/lib/openshift/***/ruby
remote: 
remote: For more details about the problem, try running the command again with the '--trace' option.
To ssh://***@treasurehunt-arakkun.rhcloud.com/~/git/treasurehunt.git/
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://***@treasurehunt-arakkun.rhcloud.com/~/git/treasurehunt.git/'
```

I tried to stop, force-stop, start and restart the app, with those results:

```
Failed to execute: 'control stop' for /var/lib/openshift/***/ruby< though the app actually Stopped

RESULT:
treasurehunt force stopped

Failed to execute: 'control start' for /var/lib/openshift/***/ruby < though the app actually Started

RESULT:
treasurehunt restarted
```

Then I created a jenkins app, and added a Jenkins client to the main app.

I do the same(random changes, add, commit, push), then it answer:

```
Counting objects: 4, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
Writing objects: 100% (4/4), 351 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 4 (delta 3), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Executing Jenkins build.
remote:
remote: You can track your build at https://jenkins-arakkun.rhcloud.com/job/treasurehunt-build
remote:
remote: Waiting for build to schedule........................................................................................................
remote: **BUILD FAILED/CANCELLED**
remote: Please see the Jenkins log for more details via 'rhc tail'
remote: !!!!!!!!
remote: Deployment Halted!
remote: If the build failed before the deploy step, your previous
remote: build is still running.  Otherwise, your application may be
remote: partially deployed or inaccessible.
remote: Fix the build and try again.
remote: !!!!!!!!
remote: An error occurred executing 'gear postreceive' (exit code: 1)
remote: Error message: CLIENT_ERROR: Failed to execute: 'control post-receive' for /var/lib/openshift/55f02e560c1e66355f000028/jenkins-client
remote:
remote: For more details about the problem, try running the command again with the '--trace' option.
To ssh://***@treasurehunt-arakkun.rhcloud.com/~/git/treasurehunt.git/
   8a2c901..3481731  master -> master
```

This is the Jenkins log

```
    Started by user Jenkins System Builder
Building remotely on treasurehuntbldr (treasurehunt-build) in workspace /var/lib/openshift/560fd2162d5271d21d00002a/app-root/runtime/repo
Checkout:repo / /var/lib/openshift/560fd2162d5271d21d00002a/app-root/runtime/repo - hudson.remoting.Channel@11e523:treasurehuntbldr
Using strategy: Default
Last Built Revision: Revision 8a2c90189bf2c4418fca52c612463d9334b68a37 (origin/HEAD, origin/master)
Checkout:repo / /var/lib/openshift/560fd2162d5271d21d00002a/app-root/runtime/repo - hudson.remoting.LocalChannel@6c5712
Wiping out workspace first.
Cloning the remote Git repository
Cloning repository origin
Fetching upstream changes from ssh://55f02e560c1e66355f000028@treasurehunt-arakkun.rhcloud.com/~/git/treasurehunt.git
Seen branch in repository origin/HEAD
Seen branch in repository origin/master
Commencing build of Revision a64bb56a363ac16c041d9908091be57dc7583f31 (origin/HEAD, origin/master)
Checking out Revision a64bb56a363ac16c041d9908091be57dc7583f31 (origin/HEAD, origin/master)
Warning : There are multiple branch changesets here
[repo] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson5827404008790235239.sh
+ source /usr/lib/openshift/cartridge_sdk/bash/sdk
++ '[' false == true ']'
++ OO_BASH_SDK=true
+ alias 'rsync=rsync --delete-after -azS -e '\''/usr/libexec/openshift/cartridges/jenkins/bin/git_ssh_wrapper.sh'\'''
+ upstream_ssh=***@treasurehunt-arakkun.rhcloud.com
+ rm -f /var/lib/openshift/560fd2162d5271d21d00002a//app-deployments/current/metadata.json
+ marker_present force_clean_build
+ '[' -f /var/lib/openshift/560fd2162d5271d21d00002a/app-root/runtime/repo//.openshift/markers/force_clean_build ']'
+ set +e
+ rsync --delete-after -azS -e /usr/libexec/openshift/cartridges/jenkins/bin/git_ssh_wrapper.sh '***@treasurehunt-arakkun.rhcloud.com:$OPENSHIFT_BUILD_DEPENDENCIES_DIR' /var/lib/openshift/560fd2162d5271d21d00002a/app-root/runtime/build-dependencies/
Warning: Permanently added 'treasurehunt-arakkun.rhcloud.com,172.16.4.63' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
+ rsync --delete-after -azS -e /usr/libexec/openshift/cartridges/jenkins/bin/git_ssh_wrapper.sh '***@treasurehunt-arakkun.rhcloud.com:$OPENSHIFT_DEPENDENCIES_DIR' /var/lib/openshift/560fd2162d5271d21d00002a/app-root/runtime/dependencies/
Warning: Permanently added 'treasurehunt-arakkun.rhcloud.com,172.16.4.63' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
+ set -e
+ gear build
Building git ref 'origin/HEAD', commit a64bb56
No such file or directory - /var/lib/openshift/560fd2162d5271d21d00002a/app-root/runtime/repo/.openshift/action_hooks/pre_build
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Archiving artifacts
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: Can you try the '--trace' option when pushing and check what's the detailed error output?

Comment: Have you tried checking your disk usage?  You can use the 'rhc app show <appname> --gears quota' command.

Comment: I remade the project from the start, since "/var/lib/openshift/560fd2162d5271d21d00002a/app-root/runtime/repo/.openshift/action_hooks/pre_build" really didn't exist on the paas.
I suspect it happened becaue I had copypasted a tempate in the home of the home, and it didn't copy all of the files it should had copied.
(Anyway, dik usage is quite low, since "Writing objects: 100% (8/8), 825 bytes ".
The --trace option can be used only from the inside of the server, probably, as it didn't let me execute git push --trace.